# Uniswapv2 "quote" ABI

Tags: blockchain, uniswap, ethereum-wallet-dapp, abi, cpp-ethereum

I am trying to sign contractof Uniswapv2 on ethereum mainnet using "quote" ABI.  the function is

```
quote(uint amountA, uint reserveA, uint reserveB)
```

I use c++ to make the raw transaction and send it to RPC-API(blastapi.io). But
where do i find reserveA and reserveB? what contract or RPC/API call i must use to obtain the "reserveA" and "resserveB? Please help...

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148107/discussion-on-question-by-biruk-damte-uniswapv2-quote-abi); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.